# Mod_rewrite only working with certain folder names

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**Context**

I'm using mod_rewrite to make my links better for SEO. I made the following rule for my page `expanded_debate.php`:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^poll/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9]+) expanded_debate.php?poll_title=$1&pollid=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

When I input this format in the URL (poll/filename/10, for example) I get a 404 error:

```
Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.46 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1h PHP/7.4.12 mod_perl/2.0.11 Perl/v5.32.0
```

However, when I change the first folder name to certain words, such as "debate" and "expanded_debate" (but not "expandedebate"), the file loads after page refresh. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^debate/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9]+) expanded_debate.php?poll_title=$1&pollid=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

works fine.

I have an older .htaccess file, titled ".htaccess11", with the following info, in case it's of any use:

```
#forbids users from going to forbidden pages
IndexIgnore *

Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#404 error directions
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

**Question**

Any idea why only certain terms in the first folder position ("^debate" in example above) work when using mod_rewrite?

There are no "poll" folders in my project, if that's of any interest.

Let me know if there are any questions.

Comment: Are there any other rules in your htaccess? Try removing the line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f` to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @Amit Verma Okay, removing that line actually fixed it. Also, adding "!" before -f fixed it, as well. Can you explain what's going on there? I'm a bit confused. Does adding the "!" mean that, if there is not a file name called "poll.php", then you can continue with the next rule?

Comment: That `RewriteCond` directive would seem to serve no purpose (and certainly looks like an error). What was the reasoning behind it? But yes, adding the `!` prefix negates the condition, so it will be successful if `/poll.php` does not exist, unless `/poll/filename.php` maps to a valid file.

Comment: @MrWhite I was just getting into mod_rewrite (and regular expressions) and followed this tutorial online, which is where this code comes from. So I didn't realize it didn't serve a purpose in this situation. Thanks for the info. If you write an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
```

Means "Take the requested URL, map it to a full local path in the normal way, append `.php` to the resulting path, and then process the following rewrite rule only if there is an existing regular file at the modified path".

For example, the URL "poll/filename/10" will be rewritten only if there is a file called "poll/filename/10.php" in the relevant location.

Since the value of the `AcceptPathInfo` directive is evidently set to `On`, this condition will also be met if there is an existing file called "poll.php" or "poll/filename.php".  That is why the rewrite rule works when you change "poll" to "debate" or "expanded_debate" – there are existing files called "debate.php" and "expanded_debate.php".

In any case, it sounds like this behavior is not what was intended.  Removing the `-f` condition should give the desired result.  Or, to prevent the rewrite rule from making existing files inaccessible, you could replace it with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

- The exclamation point negates the `-f` test: "continue only if this file does **not** exist"
- If you are using the `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` server variable (anywhere), you should be aware of how the `AcceptPathInfo` directive will affect this, and consider setting that directive explicitly in the same .htaccess file.
- If `Options +MultiViews` is in effect, then `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` will match existing files whether or not the extension is included in the request (`GET /foo` will match an existing file "foo.php", "foo.html", etc.).  And `GET /foo.php` will match in any case.  So, omit the string "\.php" from the original rule.
- Other configuration may also have an effect, too.  The important point  is that, unlike `%{REQUEST_URI}`, `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` invokes *all* the processing that Apache would otherwise do to translate a URL into a local path.

[(source)](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

---

**NB:** although I don't think it was the intention here, you actually *might* want to test for the existence of a local file as part of this rule.  You could use a `RewriteCond` to check whether the back-end data file for a given poll has been manually created, and return 404 by default if it has not.  That would be a simple way to prevent users from making up their own poll URLs at will.